# Retain Record Macro VBA on close

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am using the record macro option in a Powerpoint chart to import data from an Excel sheet. After the code is written, the code automatically gets erased after I close the chart.

Is there any way the code remains in the VBA of the chart so that I can run it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's actually happening is you're recording a macro in a temporary instance of Excel that's launched when you choose to insert a chart in PowerPoint.

What ends up in PPT is a strange sort of Chart object that contains the chart and the data required to produce it, but not actually the Excel object that you were working in.  That'd explain why the code gets tossed.

Instead of inserting a chart from within PowerPoint, start Excel, record what you need to while creating/editing a chart, then save the Excel file.  It'll contain your recorded macros, which you can then copy/paste into PPT and modify as needed.

Comment: actually I need to edit the ppt on a recurring basis. not sure if my bos will allow me to import from excel. thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

have you tried saving the powerpoint as a pptm in stead of pptx

pptm is a Macro-Enabled presentation
pptx is a normal presentation, that will not allow storing of VBA

Comment: did this answer your question? if so please mark is such (left of the answer the v shaped mark). If not, what is still unanswered?

Comment: I tried doing this. It did not work. I will try writing in the excel va itself and export from there . thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion is to write the macro in a Powerpoint code module (**NOT** in the embedded/temporary instance of Excel).

This may be more advanced than you're looking for

You will need to add a library reference to the Excel object model, but then you can then have full VBA/programmatic control over the Powerpoint chartObjects (and their datasheets), just like you would in Excel's VBE.

Comment: "Another suggestion is to record the macro in a Powerpoint code module"  --  sorry if this sounds like nit-picking, but it would be more accurate to say "write the macro in a PowerPoint code module".  PowerPoint no longer has a macro recorder.  Excel does.  That's why I suggested recording the code in Excel then pasting it into a module in PowerPoint.  But as to putting the code in PPT itself, definitely.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg you're absolutely correct about that. I've updated my answer.